# How does this recursive code change my list?

Tags: java, recursion

i have tried  running and debugging  the following code in IntellIj in order to track what each line of my code does but i still dont understand the result.

```java
public static void testMyFun() {  

  List<Integer> xs = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    xs.add(i);  

  myFun(xs,2);

  System.out.println(xs);  
}   


public static <A> void myFun (List<A> xs, int n) {  
  if (n > 0) {   

    A x = xs.get(0);  

    xs.remove(0); 

    xs.add(x); 

    myFun(xs, n-1);    
}
```

The result that i get is [ 2,3,4,0,1] 
How does 0 and 1 go to the end of the list?

Comment: in your recursive function, you get the first item from the array, save it in a local variable `x`, remove it from the list and add the `x` to the list (which adds it to the end of it). The recursive function runs `n` times - which means `n` items will be moved from the beginning of the array to the end of it.

Comment: As you can see from the code the method is generic so A refers to a generic variable.

Comment: @galando so when it adds it again it adds it to the end of the list basically?

Comment: @Erlan A will be integer?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes.

Comment: It is simple shifting element on list using recursion. Your for loop is just adding values and thats it, because loops end it scope after add to list. Method call is after loop is done. Adding elements to list is to to end of list.

Comment: @RANDB yes. take a look here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set *n* as 2. So essentially myFun() will be executed twice at most. myFun() is removing the first element of the list and re-adding it to the back. Since this can only occur twice, the first two element (0 and 1) will be sent to the back of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you execute `myFun({0,1,2,3,4},2);`.

This executes `myFun({1,2,3,4,0},1);`.

The next myFun executed is `myFun({2,3,4,0,1},0);`, which immedietly stops.

This is, because you remove the first element and add it at the end(`add()` appends it at the end)

Comment: It will be executed a third time, but it would do nothing because `n>0` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
A x = xs.get(0);  

xs.remove(0); 

xs.add(x);
```

moves first element to last position

```
if (n > 0) {
```

while `n is > 0`

and you start with

```
myFun(xs,2);
```

and recurse call N times due to `myFun(xs,n-1);`

so you move 2 first element to the end of array

Answer (score 0):

The function "myFun " removes n element from the list , then add them again to the list. 
The add method add the element in the end of the list. 
Because you sent n=2 . myFun  will remove 0,1 fron the "head" of the list and move then to the end of the list.

Comment: Because , when i=0 xs is an empty ArrayList . therefor adding to the end of the list will be just xs=[0]. Then when i =1 xs's size is also 1 , then adding to the end will be xs=[0,1] and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Original  list values:

```
01234
```

When n =2 list modified to

```
12340
```

When n=1  list modified to

```
23401
```

When n reaches 0 recursion will stop.
And items current order in the list will be

```
23401
```

Comment: Note: your logic will simply move the first item in the list to the last index

Answer (score -1):

That's so simple.
Recursive function will be run twice, for n=2 and n=1, when it is 0 if clause don't run and myFun will be finish.